Unable to add Apple Wallet Pass at this time .pkpass - icon.png, manifest's listed doesn't match computed hash
I'm using a script to create my pass for apple wallet, I've gone through all the steps and double checked my JSON and my files and file sizes. Certificates are validated as good. The hash in manifest matches but when I run it through simulator I get the following error:
error   16:23:16.585688+1200    Passbook    Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.whitelawmitchell.ToothCompany/p69f2J. For file icon.png, manifest's listed SHA1 hash gTWZcdeNNxGU1dceXF4lN5s9ono= doesn't match computed hash, 81359971d78d371194d5d71e5c5e25379b3da27a
error   16:23:16.590540+1200    Passbook    Failed to add pass: 'file:///Users/whitelawdesign/Documents/Personal/wallets/membership.pass/storecard.pkpass' Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c556b0 {Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "For file icon.png, manifest's listed SHA1 hash gTWZcdeNNxGU1dceXF4lN5s9ono= doesn't match computed hash, 81359971d78d371194d5d71e5c5e25379b3da27a" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=For file icon.png, manifest's listed SHA1 hash gTWZcdeNNxGU1dceXF4lN5s9ono= doesn't match computed hash, 81359971d78d371194d5d71e5c5e25379b3da27a}}}.

this is my script

#!/bin/bash

# Set variables
P12_CERT="certificates.p12"
CERT_PASSPHRASE="nikond60"
PASS_TYPE_IDENTIFIER="pass.com.whitelawmitchell.ToothCompany"
TEAM_IDENTIFIER="PSGZTYDDF5"
CERT_PEM="certificate.pem"
KEY_PEM="key.pem"
KEY_NOENC_PEM="key-noenc.pem"
WWDR_PEM="WWDR.pem"
ROOT_CERT="AppleIncRootCertificate.pem"
COMBINED_CA="combined-ca.pem"
MANIFEST="manifest.json"
SIGNATURE="signature"
PKPASS_FILE="storecard.pkpass"

# Extract certificate and key from the .p12 file
echo "Extracting certificate and keys from .p12 file..."
openssl pkcs12 -in "$P12_CERT" -clcerts -nokeys -out "$CERT_PEM" -passin pass:"$CERT_PASSPHRASE" -legacy
openssl pkcs12 -in "$P12_CERT" -nocerts -out "$KEY_PEM" -passin pass:"$CERT_PASSPHRASE" -passout pass:"$CERT_PASSPHRASE" -legacy
openssl rsa -in "$KEY_PEM" -out "$KEY_NOENC_PEM" -passin pass:"$CERT_PASSPHRASE"

# Verify the extracted certificate
echo "Verifying the certificate..."
openssl verify -CAfile "$ROOT_CERT" -untrusted "$WWDR_PEM" "$CERT_PEM"

# Create the manifest file
echo "Creating manifest file..."
cat <<EOF >"$MANIFEST"
{
  "icon.png": "gTWZcdeNNxGU1dceXF4lN5s9ono=",
  "icon@2x.png": "Vu923Gp5gMx1K78+UTcDZllRXFQ=",
  "icon@3x.png": "PinMB32ggBF7G4DhxbP4IYMWvoQ=",
  "logo.png": "HBJLqdLz+q4iY4ZcZoAoiHrSB+o=",
  "strip.png": "345XiBA+L2wMKtknghkK9xN7Fi8=",
  "strip@2x.png": "bZQt2Dxlz+eG4NbOMOO+tiA1UzA=",
  "pass.json": "r/LAj6IgGhBBVSSnJsqPhvzyfZI="
}
EOF

# Create the combined CA file
echo "Creating combined CA file..."
cat "$CERT_PEM" "$WWDR_PEM" "$ROOT_CERT" > "$COMBINED_CA"

# Sign the manifest file to create the signature
echo "Signing the manifest file..."
openssl smime -binary -sign -signer "$CERT_PEM" -inkey "$KEY_NOENC_PEM" -in "$MANIFEST" -outform DER -certfile "$COMBINED_CA" -out "$SIGNATURE"

# Verify the signature
echo "Verifying the signature..."
openssl smime -verify -in "$SIGNATURE" -inform DER -content "$MANIFEST" -CAfile "$COMBINED_CA" -purpose any

# Check if verification was successful
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Verification failed."
  exit 1
fi

# Create the .pkpass file
echo "Creating the .pkpass file..."
zip -r "$PKPASS_FILE" pass.json "$MANIFEST" "$SIGNATURE" icon.png icon@2x.png icon@3x.png logo.png strip.png strip@2x.png

# Verify the contents of the .pkpass file
echo "Verifying the contents of the .pkpass file..."
unzip -l "$PKPASS_FILE"

echo "Process complete."


